# mysql fetch assoc used in url fetching

Tags: php, mysql

i have a script in which output  **localhost/urlfromMysqlDatabase**

i need  output should be **urlfromMysqlDatabase**

please give me any suggestions to changes this script

```
$link = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT url FROM admins"));
```

and in between html body i have a code

```
<a href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>" target="_self">
```

Comment: url in database contain external website links

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`<a href="<?php echo @end(explode("/", $link['url'])); ?>" target="_self">`

`end(explode("/", $link['url']))` will print out `urlfromMysqlDatabase` (everything after the last slash `/`).

Answer (score 0):

```
$link = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT url FROM admins"));
$link=end(explode("/",$link['url']));


<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" target="_self">
```